# PHPseclib whether I need to close the connection?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I have two questions.

1.I am using SFTP with private key and connecting through the phpseclib.Whether I need to close the connection or it will automatically close the connection.If I need to close how can I do it?

2.How to resume the upload if it is failure with phpseclib?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're using PHP5 the connection will close automatically because of the destructor.
2. I don't think resuming uploads is currently possible.  Might be something you want to ask the phpseclib author about adding.